# How to pass a value to Jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Please look at following code

user.js

```
exports.index = function (req, res){
  res.render('user', {
        id: req.params.id
    });
};
```

user.jade

```
body
    - var x = #{id}
        div.container
            div.headpic
            if (x < 10)
                img(src='http://domain.com/head/000'+ x + '.png')
```

I want to pass the value id to x, but show error '500 Unexpected character '#'', so how is the right way to pass the value? thanks.

Comment: @tymeJV thanks, but it doesn't work with error 500 Unexpected token punc «}», expected punc «:»

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you dont need the #{}. just the id will work

```
- var x = id
```